# Detect tap only on main node/parent, not child nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a moving SKSpriteNode where i detect taps on the scene with TouchesBegan based on the nodes name. 
This worked perfectly, until i addeed a SKEmitterNode as a child to the moving node leaving a trail of circles behind the moving node.

My touches on the main/parent node is now detected when the SKEmitterNode particle trail is being touched.

How can i only detect touches on my main/parent spritenode, but not on the child nodes of this sprite?

**When the sparks that ouside node1.size is tapped, why is "node1" returned in touchesbegan and not "emitter"?**

Example GameScene.swift

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(400, 300))
    node1.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
    node1.name = "node1"
    addChild(node1)

    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")
    emitter.name = "emitter"
    emitter.zPosition = -1
    node1.addChild(emitter)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    let touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

    println(touchedNode.name)
}
```

Comment: can you set the `userInetractionEnabled` property for each node

Comment: I have tried, its not working. Think it's because im not interacting with the nodes, just checking which nodes are where at a current location in my scene.

Comment: your code will not work on swift 2.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it setting the SKEmitterNode´s targetnode property to another node other than the one im detecting taps on.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/targetNode

```
emitter.targetNode = self.scene
```